# Problem of compatibility c program Cent Os and Mint

Tags: c, linux, graphics, compilation, sdl

I'm new in C development and i recently succeed to program John Conway's Game of life

As a matter of fact i developed this program on Cent OS and it works succesfully.
I worked with SDL library and i draw lines with the coordinates of the window that is 1000x500

However as soon as i get on linux mint there is a display problem :
the screen flashes and everything seems to be redo agains because of the coordinates.

First i had a problem with de compilation on linux mint(even if on cent os it was perfect) , i re installed everything on mint and now the program run but with problems

here's the first part of my program that shloud create a grid but the lines are unequal in mint but good in centos
i didn't put the code where when i click on a square it makes it black but each time i click the display get full black and flashes sometimes
heres the main program run.c

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{ 
int largeur=  1000;
int hauteur = 500;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL; 
SDL_Window *window=NULL;
SDL_Event event;
SDL_bool quit=SDL_FALSE;
SDL_Color fond_blanc = {255,255,255,255};

int x;
int y;
int nbr;
int dep=0;
printf("--------Bienvenue au jeu de la vie !! \n");




if(0!= SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
{
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}




window = SDL_CreateWindow("Le jeu de la vie : Erwan",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,largeur,hauteur,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);


if(0!=SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,fond_blanc.r
,fond_blanc.g,fond_blanc.b,fond_blanc.a)){printf("ok1\n");}

    if(0!=SDL_RenderClear(renderer)){printf("ok3\n");}

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
/*END OF CREATION OF WHITE BACKGROUND*/

/*LINES*/
    SDL_Point point[largeur];
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t kt= 0;
    size_t kz =0;
int c = 0;

/*creation of horizontal lines*/
while(c<hauteur/20)
{
for(i = 0; i < largeur; i++)
{
    point[i].x = i;
    point[i].y = c*20;
}
SDL_RenderDrawPoints(renderer, point, largeur);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

c +=1;
}

    SDL_Point point2[hauteur];
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    i = 0;
c = 0;


/*creation of vertical lines*/
while(c<(largeur/20))
{
for(i = 0; i < hauteur; i++)
{
    point2[i].x = c*20;
    point2[i].y = i;
}
SDL_RenderDrawPoints(renderer, point2, hauteur);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

c +=1;
}





printf("Closing don't touch anything\n ");
SDL_Delay(1000);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and here's the compilation line :

```
gcc run.c -o main -lSDL2
```

and to run the prog i use
`./main`
Sorry for the code it's kind of unreadable i think
Do you have an idea of why and does that mean i have to re code everything for different distribution of linux ?

Thanks !

Comment: Better to post the code than only lightly describe it.  I suspect an issue with screen buffering.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mre]. The code cannot be compiled without a file `fonctions.h`. Please indent your code properly. Show the commands you use to build and run the program and the input if any. You rarely need to code for different Linux distributions, but you might need to handle different incompatible library versions. Do the two systems have different screen sizes? Is your program implemented for a specific size?

Comment: yes sorry, both system are in 1280x800 , and the window is create at a static size so i was thinking that is wasn't going to be a problem

Comment: Shouldn't you call creation and affichage somewhere?

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Indent your code to make it readable. It doesn't really look minimal. Try to remove or to simplify parts in a way that you can still reproduce the problem. Putting everything what is needed in a single file would make it easier for us to compile and run the program. Showing the commands that get executed by `make` would be better than showing a Makefile that seems to require a specific directory structure.

Comment: You’re calling SDL_RenderPresent more than once per frame. Don’t do this.